# How to undervolt a Core i3 laptop?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i3, undervolting, cool-n-quiet

Using [k10stat](http://sites.google.com/site/k10stat/), I significantly undervolted all 3 p-states of my Athlon II P320 laptop, yielding a 10-20% longer battery run time. Are there similar tools for Intel's Clarkdale/Arrandale processors? And what about Core 2?

For those not familiar with k10stat: what I want to do is to modify the frequency and voltage values of the CPU p-states used by Intel's EIST (AMD's Cool'n'Quiet).

Comment: For those who own an Athlon II P320: I undervolted from 1.15/1.0375/0.8625 to 0.95/0.8375/0.725 and all 3 states are prime95 stable. Temperature lowered by 8 deg C at full load. I love it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so far, and possibly never. see post #5

http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/451851-rmclock-undervolting-i3-5-processors.html

> I don’t think you will find a core i5 or an i7 without a dedicated on processor power microprocessor which has ultimate control of the behavior of the CPU depending upon its intended deployment environment (desktop, mobile, etc…) unless it’s an E or engineering sample in which case I don’t think I would want it in my machine, I’ve had them and well, they’re dodgy at best. Spoke with some real high level hardware engineers on my last business trip and they agree. i5 and i7 are going to be managed by Intel as far as power management, P states, multipliers, voltages etc… The BIOS will have to have the necessary logic to accomodate this but will not be able to override it nor will an OS driver. That’s about it on this one, then again I hope I’m wrong and after all… what do I know, I don’t work at Intel!